# Displaying html of page only if session exists

Tags: php

```
  <?php

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "errorlog.log");


$recid= $_POST['recid'];
$username = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ownername = $_POST['ownername'];

include ("connection.php");


$result = $db->query("UPDATE users SET verified='y' WHERE recid='$recid'"); 

$filename = str_replace(" ","_", trim($username) );
mkdir("Business_Pages/". $filename."/");



$jquery = "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'> </script>";
$jqueryui = "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js'> </script>";
$jquerycss = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>";
$postdata = "<script src='../../Scripts/postdata.js'> </script>";
$pagecss = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../CSS/businesspages.css'>";
$wclogo = "<img src='../../wc.png' id='wc'>";
$postinput = "<input type='text' id='post' placeholder='Post' name='post'>";
$postdate = "<input type='text' id='date' placeholder='Enter Date' name='date'>";
$accountinfo = "<table id='accountinfo'> <tr> <td> <img src='../../testresteraunt.png' id='testresteraunt'> </td> </tr> <tr>                     <td> $username </td> </tr> <tr> <td> $ownername </td> </tr> </table>";
$links = "<table id='links'> <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr> </table> <div id='header'>";

$fp = fopen("Business_Pages/". $filename . "/" . $filename . ".html", "w");

fwrite($fp,"<?php session_start()");


fwrite($fp,"if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>");

fwrite($fp,"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>");

fwrite($fp,"</head>");

fwrite($fp,"<body>");

fwrite($fp,"</body> </html>");

fwrite($fp,"<?php } ?>");

fclose($fp);

$to = "$email";
$subject = "Account Creation";
$message = "Congratulations you have been accepted to Wolfeboro Connection";
$from = "info@wolfeboroconnection.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)

?>
```

Im trying only to show the html if a session is valid but php is saying that its an unexpected if statement and 
**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in **/home/content/96/10688096/html/verify.php** on line **37**
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `fp` and `fwrite`.. Do you want to show the page in the browser or want to write it into the file...??

Comment: Be careful with interpolation: depending on earlier code in the script, `"if( isset($_SESSION=['id')) { ?>"` might not output what you expect.  If `$_SESSION` is an array like it should be, the relevant line in the output file would read `if( isset(array=['id')) { ?>`.

Comment: correct i want to fwrite it to a file and my login goes to that file but i want it to not go to the file if you dont login

Comment: Well, instead of writing a file, what you can do is to define the file and specify the condition to check whether the session exists or not. If not, the user will be redirected to login page or somewhere else. otherwise the page will be shown...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to display the page on the browser then you should do following instead of writing the file and then showing it. Just write below code into the file you want to check the session.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body></body> </html>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Ok I found the error.. Check out below line

```
fwrite($fp,"if(isset(".$_SESSION['id'].")) { ?>");
```

Place this in your code and it should work correctly.. Let me know if any further problem arises...

Hey, This is the latest code I've tried on my machine and it worked... Have a look on it and let me know the results..

```
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "errorlog.log");

$fp = fopen("newtest.php", "w");
fwrite($fp,"<?php session_start();");
fwrite($fp,"if(isset(\$_SESSION['id'])) { ?>");
fwrite($fp,"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>");
fwrite($fp,"</head>");
fwrite($fp,"<body>");
fwrite($fp,"</body> </html>");
fwrite($fp,"<?php } ?>");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thats what is being written to the file as html and php im getting a error  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Well I haven't received that error.. you might be missing something.. Place your full code into the question.. there might be something which is being missed...

Comment: @PhilPilon.. Try `fwrite($fp,"<?php session_start();");`.. It might be because of missing semi-colon... Let me know the results..

Comment: @PhilPilon... I've changed the answer.. have you tried it.. Let me know the results if you can..

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
if( isset($_SESSION=['id')) {
```

you have unwanted = sign

try this

```
if( isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
```

Comment: You missed something in the statement.. `if( isset($_SESSION['id')) { ` should be like `if( isset($_SESSION['id'])) { `.. missing `]`..